# How do I bundle previous DatePicker String?

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I use a DatePicker fragment to get a date from the user.

```
...
c = Calendar.getInstance();
year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) ;
month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
    this, year, month, day);
return picker;

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    final EditText txtDate;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
    txtDate = (EditText) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().findViewById(R.id.FEditText);

    String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy" + " ";  \\ *** formatted with "yy" to fit on EditText line rather than "yyyy"
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
    txtDate.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));        
}
```

In MainActivity, I want to get the original DatePicker date, say February 28, 2017 that is set on the EditText line and put it back into the DatePicker fragment as the current date when the user clicks on the date to edit it.  The EditText line shows the date as "yy" for the year, so 02/28/17.  I assume I need to convert the EditText data back to "yyyy" from "yy" to put the Date parts into a bundle and then set the Date into the DatePicker fragment.

```
fListenerEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Extract the previously entered date from the EditText line as a string
    String dateStr = fListenerEditText.getText().toString().replace(" ", "");

    String myFormat2 = "MM/dd/yyyy" + " ";  \\ *** I assume I need to put "yyyy" back into the DatePicker not "yy" so need to re-format the Date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat2, Locale.US);
    String formattedDate = sdf2.format(dateStr); \\ *** wrong here?

    String[]dateParts = formattedDate.split("/");
    c.set(Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2]),Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0])-1,Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]));
    Bundle argsbundle = new Bundle();
    argsbundle.putInt("year", c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    argsbundle.putInt("month", c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    argsbundle.putInt("day", c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.setArguments(argsbundle);
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

When I click on the EditText line, the DatePicker opens as expected but I don't get the previous date, I get January 01 1900.  What am I missing here with the formatting?

Comment: Are you updating the `DatePicker` date using `picker.UpdateDate()` after selecting and clicking the `OK` button?

Comment: No I just use an onDismiss method with a DatePicker dialog that closes the DatePicker when the user clicks "Done".

Comment: Try using the `onPositiveClick` callback and update your `DatePicker` inside it by using `picker.UpdateDate(yourSelectedDate)`, and once you open it again, it will be updated to the last selected date. **Don't forget to make a global instance of your `DatePicker`**

Comment: Ok I will try.  The global instance would be so there are no memory leaks?  If yes, can you show example?  I am Android newbie...

Comment: okay, going to write my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your `DatePickerDialog` by using the `updateDate(yourSelectedDate)` method as follows:

In your `Activity` class create a global instance of the `DatePickerDialog`:

```
public class CustomDatePicker extends Activity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


    private DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(...);
        //....
        Calendar uCal = Calendar.getInstance();

        mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            this,
            uCal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            uCal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            uCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        mDatePickerDialog.updateDate(year, month, day);
    }
}
```

After that, using the `onDateSet` method to update your `mDPDialog` values (selectedYear, selectedMonth and selectedDay)

Comment: Ok so I don't need a fragment file then?  I see you just use a DatePicker class, extend MainActivity and then set a global instance of the dialog.  I will try it.

Comment: Should "mDPDialog" in onDateSet() be "mDatePickerDialog"?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer, and yes, you can use it simply like this rather than using a `Fragment`

Comment: Excellent.  Will give it a try and then circle back for upvote.  Cheers.

Comment: Good, let me know if it works with you. I am here to help

Comment: Very good.  It seems much simpler/efficient to just add the global instance of the DatePicker dialog in the Activity as you recommend.  I read that Fragments and their lifecycle are more complex, so to be avoided if possible?  With Android methods I've learned less code and less complexity is almost always "more"...any thoughts on this?

Comment: Actually, handling `Fragment` lifecycle has more complexity and needs more attention specially when starting/finishing an `Activity` and regarding the "more" term, the more you have code the more complexity your code would be

Comment: Do I need to add "private Context mContext" as a global context variable since you have mContext, this" in the constructor for the new DatePickerDialog?

Comment: Nope, I forgot to edit my answer for `Activity` class. You only need to write `this` instead of `mContext`, check my updated answer

Comment: A bit confused here.  I have all of my EditTexts and ClickListeners in my Activity file.  How do I use the onClick() on the EditText line in the Activity to launch the CustomDatePicker class?

Comment: Ok I used show() to launch Dialog if EditText line for the Date was empty.  Last piece is if the EditText line already has a Date in it and the user clicks on the line to revise the Date.  How do I use onDateSet() to put the selected Year, Month and Day into the DatePicker upon launch?

Comment: I tried to run mDatePickerDialog.show(); from OnClick on the EditText line but received NullPointerException.  Any ideas on how to launch the DatePickerDialog from the onClick on the EditText?

Comment: You have to initialize your `DatePickerDialog` before calling `.show()` method. If you want to see your last selected date values (year, month, day) when you open your `DatePickerDialog`, you can use `SharedPreferences` to save last selected values and initialize your `DatePickerDialog` with them.